# clear Textbox on the first click

Tags: php, html, css

I have a text box that I want to clear out on the first click and not after. I saw this is possible by using javascript. But my server at school block javascript and I am having to do this task without it. I am using PHP and html code in my program. Please let me know if this is possible.

**Code:**

```
<?php
    echo "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">Date info: <input id=\"Description\"  type=\"date\" name=\"Description\" \" value =\" mm/dd/yyyy\">
    <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" /></form>";

    $test_date = (string)$_POST['Description']; 
    if( .....
    ...
    ..
    .
?>
```

Comment: Can we have look at your JavaScript code which is being blocked, since this should not be case of blocking JavaScript until its suspicious.

Comment: Could you not post to the same page and use PHP to control the content of your input boxes - so on first click of the button you'll have to submit the form, which empties the input box.... The downside to this is you're refreshing the page as your posting to it.  Am I on the right lines for what you're requesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a placeholder attribute instead of a default value?  This is essentially cleared on the first click and only restored when the element is blurred if the textbox is empty.  It's not suitable if you want users to be able to edit the pre-defined content of the textbox though.

Also using the default value you've specified for a date input isn't necessary - the browser will enforce the correct date format for you.

Answer (score 0):

You totally need javascript for that because there is no way to add similar to javaScript's "onclick" event in only css and clear textarea by that event. If you want to do that after clicking submit button it is possible via php of course but not without submitting it.